# Python scraper does return empty

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have the following code to scrape the statistics of a Football match from flashscore:`

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
from collections import defaultdict

url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/fXAklYDd/#match-statistics;0'

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_scores():
    r = await asession.get(url)
    await r.html.arender()
    return r

results = asession.run(get_scores)
results = results[0]

stats = results.html.find("div.statRow")

dict_res = defaultdict(list)

for ind in range(len(stats)):
    dict_res['stats'].append(stats[ind].text)

df_res = pd.DataFrame(dict_res)
print(df_res)
```

Where the line `stats = results.html.find("div.statRow")` should return the statistics of the match
This generates the following output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?
I do not understand why it does not show the statistics in a DataFrame.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the page you are trying to get is dynamically generated and that `requests_html` does not deal with such situation I guess.. Try another library, e.g. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await r.html.arender(sleep = 1)
```

Just had a reading at the documentation of requests_html and found out that the sleep value to be helpful in this case

This is the output:

```
0   59%\nBall Possession\n41%
1       16\nGoal Attempts\n12
2         5\nShots on Goal\n5
3        5\nShots off Goal\n5
4         6\nBlocked Shots\n2
5          3\nCorner Kicks\n5
6              1\nOffsides\n1
7      3\nGoalkeeper Saves\n4
8               11\nFouls\n24
9          2\nYellow Cards\n3
10     422\nTotal Passes\n305
11            19\nTackles\n17
12           122\nAttacks\n94
13  46\nDangerous Attacks\n39
14  62%\nBall Possession\n38%
15        4\nGoal Attempts\n8
16        1\nShots on Goal\n4
17       1\nShots off Goal\n3
18        2\nBlocked Shots\n1
19         0\nCorner Kicks\n3
20             1\nOffsides\n0
21     3\nGoalkeeper Saves\n0
22               3\nFouls\n14
23         0\nYellow Cards\n1
24     231\nTotal Passes\n139
25              8\nTackles\n4
26            67\nAttacks\n36
27  20\nDangerous Attacks\n19
28  56%\nBall Possession\n44%
29       12\nGoal Attempts\n4
30        4\nShots on Goal\n1
31       4\nShots off Goal\n2
32        4\nBlocked Shots\n1
33         3\nCorner Kicks\n2
34             0\nOffsides\n1
35     0\nGoalkeeper Saves\n4
36               8\nFouls\n10
37         2\nYellow Cards\n2
38     191\nTotal Passes\n166
39            11\nTackles\n13
40            55\nAttacks\n58
41  26\nDangerous Attacks\n20
```

To clean the output from the break lines you need to use replace("\n", " ") at the end of the append

```
for ind in range(len(stats)):
    dict_res['stats'].append(stats[ind].text.replace("\n", " "))
```

Here is the output afterwards:

```
0   59% Ball Possession 41%
1       16 Goal Attempts 12
2         5 Shots on Goal 5
3        5 Shots off Goal 5
4         6 Blocked Shots 2
5          3 Corner Kicks 5
6              1 Offsides 1
7      3 Goalkeeper Saves 4
8               11 Fouls 24
9          2 Yellow Cards 3
10     422 Total Passes 305
11            19 Tackles 17
12           122 Attacks 94
13  46 Dangerous Attacks 39
14  62% Ball Possession 38%
15        4 Goal Attempts 8
16        1 Shots on Goal 4
17       1 Shots off Goal 3
18        2 Blocked Shots 1
19         0 Corner Kicks 3
20             1 Offsides 0
21     3 Goalkeeper Saves 0
22               3 Fouls 14
23         0 Yellow Cards 1
24     231 Total Passes 139
25              8 Tackles 4
26            67 Attacks 36
27  20 Dangerous Attacks 19
28  56% Ball Possession 44%
29       12 Goal Attempts 4
30        4 Shots on Goal 1
31       4 Shots off Goal 2
32        4 Blocked Shots 1
33         3 Corner Kicks 2
34             0 Offsides 1
35     0 Goalkeeper Saves 4
36               8 Fouls 10
37         2 Yellow Cards 2
38     191 Total Passes 166
39            11 Tackles 13
40            55 Attacks 58
41  26 Dangerous Attacks 20
```